# How strong is public opinion that the West is too soft on Putin?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, public-opinion

What are the poll results regarding how many people think that the international community and the West are too soft on Putin by more or less allowing Russia to destroy Ukraine and Ukrainians?

Comment: This is not a site for debate, but for question and answers. If you can reformat it as something other than a request for opinions, it might be salvageable as on-topic.

Comment: I take it you want to know polling results? Or something else?

Comment: It is imposible to know what people exactly think.

Comment: How strong is public opinion in which country?

Answer (score 6):

Germany, a [poll](https://www.tagesschau.de/inland/deutschlandtrend/deutschlandtrend-3037.html) by the broadcaster ARD. Among other things:

- 29% believe that German arms deliveries are insufficient, 42% believe they are appropriate, 23% think they go too far.
- 41% believe that German sanctions are insufficient, 37% think they are appropriate, 15% think they go too far.
- 41% believe that German diplomacy is insufficient, 43% think it is appropriate, 8% think it goes too far.
- 50% believe that the German government should show strength against Russia, 43% believe it should be careful not to provoke it.

So public opinion is somewhere between "just right" and "too soft."

The ARD has a reasonably solid reputation in Germany, but a vocal minority considers it "mainstream media controlled by the elites." 1,337 participants from May 30th to June 1st.

Comment: But ARD is mainstream media controlled by the state and it has prooven to distribute some wrong information, like for example about Russia bombing its own cities.

Comment: @convert, I guess you belong to that vocal minority I mentioned in the last paragraph.

Comment: Is there any margin of error for 1337 participants, if extrapolated to 80 million? I guess up to 5% would be reasonable.

Comment: @Trilarion, 3% I believe, but in a question like this it is much more criticial that the data is almost a month old. Note that such an error would still support my conclusion -- the average sits on the margin of "just right" leaning towards "too soft."

Comment: @o.m. Why you think it´s minority? Even some mainstream journalists have confirmed that ARD is biased.

Comment: @convert Then these some mainstream journalists are a minority. Believe me, I talk with a lot of Germans and ARD is one of the most trustworthy sources for them. But this could surely be another question. How independent is public TV in Germany for example?

Comment: @Trilarion No that journalist is defenetly not part of any "minority", he´s very famous and was working for ARD.

Comment: @convert, "some" journalists have just become "that" journalist. There **are** some Germans who believe the Russian view. Most do not.

Comment: @o.m. But the one I am tallking about shares the western view.

Comment: @convert, still no name to google, and how does a journalist "share the western view" and "confirm the ARD is biased" at the same time? Are you assuming there is an opinion dictated by elites, or not?

Comment: @o.m. I am talking abou Günter Jauch, but not shure if you´ll find that article in english.

Comment: @convert, Günther Jauch used to be a *sports* journalist, then a *game show* host. Calling him a *journalist* these days is really stretching things.

Comment: @o.m. Unfortunatly I have the link to article only in german where he tallks about his political tallkshow in ARD.

Comment: @convert, so you got one talk show host who is a former sports journalist to support your viewpoint. There are actually *many* more, hardly a surprise considering that a couple of percent of the German population support this viewpoint. The AfD, which shares what seems to be your view, is currently polling at 12%.

Comment: @o.m. Looks like you still misunderstanding me. Günther Jauch had a political tallkshow and he is defenetly not prorussian or asociated in a ny way with AFD.

Comment: @convert, I don't see what there is to misunderstand. I wrote for context that the ARD is **generally** accepted as a reputable news source in Germany. You keep bringing up one entertainer who disagrees. There is even an entire political party which disagrees, but I stand by the **generally.** In a democracy it would be very strange if everybody agrees on some issue.